# How to link multiple accounts together for Meteor accounts?

Tags: meteor, accounts

I would like that user could link his or her account on my Meteor site to multiple external authentication mechanisms, so that he or she can use any of them and get into the same common account on the site. The idea is that user can authenticate against Facebook and Twitter and then my site can use API for both to Facebook and Twitter to interact in the user's name. What is the best way to do that? So to allow user, once user is already logged in, to "link" to additional authentication mechanisms. And that no matter which authentication mechanism he or she uses, the user gets the same user account/object after login?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a solution for this (not straightforward):

http://ondrej-kvasnovsky.blogspot.com/2013/07/meteor-how-to-login-with-github-account.html

Answer (score 0):

Try mondora-connect-with package ([here](https://atmospherejs.com/mondora/connect-with) or [here](https://github.com/mondora/mondora-connect-with/)).